# Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

i'm using identityserver4  for SSO problem was whenever i restart identityserver client application gets exception for the first time exception message was

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Unhandled remote failure.
>   (IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid':
>   'e57439c26753f8a940888050ab3860fa',
>         token: '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"e57439c26753f8a940888050ab3860fa"}.{"nbf":1505114113,"exp":1505114413,"iss":"http://recruiterinsider-qa.wiseatom.com:85","aud":"empite.rip","nonce":"636407108987016790.OTIyYzNhOGYtZmY1OS00NDQyLThmNDUtYWNkOTA1NDEyM2JmYTlkYWRjNDMtNDRmMC00YmQxLWI2MGQtOTI2MDYzNDYxMTUy","iat":1505114113,"c_hash":"Bc0qZ4ezhn0-wB-e9rDp8g","sid":"135b1b1f352674ab3b80846fef6ad0d8","sub":"94e570f7-920f-426e-b0db-e4f871323149","auth_time":1505114112,"idp":"local","amr":["pwd"]}'.)
>   System.AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure. (IDX10501:
>   Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid':
>   'e57439c26753f8a940888050ab3860fa', token:
>   '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"e57439c26753f8a940888050ab3860fa"}.{"nbf":1505114113,"exp":1505114413,"iss":"http://recruiterinsider-qa.wiseatom.com:85","aud":"empite.rip","nonce":"636407108987016790.OTIyYzNhOGYtZmY1OS00NDQyLThmNDUtYWNkOTA1NDEyM2JmYTlkYWRjNDMtNDRmMC00YmQxLWI2MGQtOTI2MDYzNDYxMTUy","iat":1505114113,"c_hash":"Bc0qZ4ezhn0-wB-e9rDp8g","sid":"135b1b1f352674ab3b80846fef6ad0d8","sub":"94e570f7-920f-426e-b0db-e4f871323149","auth_time":1505114112,"idp":"local","amr":["pwd"]}'.)
>   ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException:
>   IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid':
>   'e57439c26753f8a940888050ab3860fa', token:
>   '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"e57439c26753f8a940888050ab3860fa"}.{"nbf":1505114113,"exp":1505114413,"iss":"http://recruiterinsider-qa.wiseatom.com:85","aud":"empite.rip","nonce":"636407108987016790.OTIyYzNhOGYtZmY1OS00NDQyLThmNDUtYWNkOTA1NDEyM2JmYTlkYWRjNDMtNDRmMC00YmQxLWI2MGQtOTI2MDYzNDYxMTUy","iat":1505114113,"c_hash":"Bc0qZ4ezhn0-wB-e9rDp8g","sid":"135b1b1f352674ab3b80846fef6ad0d8","sub":"94e570f7-920f-426e-b0db-e4f871323149","auth_time":1505114112,"idp":"local","amr":["pwd"]}'.
>   at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String
>   token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String
>   token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken&
>   validatedToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateToken(String
>   idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties,
>   TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, JwtSecurityToken& jwt)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRemoteCallbackAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.<HandleRequestAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)

so i change `AddTemporarySigningCredential` to `AddDeveloperSigningCredential` still i'm getting error when ever i restart identityserver

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Producer and Consumer use the same key material? Found this on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239261/cannot-validate-accesstoken-with-identityserver

Comment: Afraid you really need to help us reproduce the issue to be able to help you...

Answer (score -1):

Your issue could be related to this. Check the [official docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html#testing-the-client)

> During development you might sometimes see an exception stating that
>   the token could not be validated. This is due to the fact that the
>   signing key material is created on the fly and kept in-memory only.
>   This exception happens when the client and IdentityServer get out of
>   sync. Simply repeat the operation at the client, the next time the
>   metadata has caught up, and everything should work normal again.

Comment: so what is the solution?